# Add directories to $PATH without repeating yourself

Tags: unity, 13.04, startup, environment-variables, zsh

My shell is `zsh` and OS is Ubuntu 13.04

I need to add directory to $PATH to make it work in following places:

- In graphical environment(Unity) (such as startup applications, `gmrun` program that runs by shortcut (it's basically as "Run command" on alt+f2)
- In terminal in Unity
- In terminal on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

I've added it in `.profile` and it works for first two points, but not the last. I know I may add it to `.zshrc` but In this case it will be wrote in tow places (violates DRY) and in the case of terminal inside unity it'll be two times in `$PATH` (I don't think it's very bad but it's at least not pretty)

If I add it only to `.zshrc` it works only for second and third cases(obviously)

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried just adding it to `.zsh` and skipping `.profile`. Also, consider moving the last sentence to the beginning of your question.

Comment: @edwin in that case it's not in PATH for graphical apps: first in my list

Comment: At least for the second and third cases `.zsh` should be enough. Try adding it to `.bashrc` as well.

Comment: Sure it's enough for 2nd and 3rd. Seems that bashrc isn't connected here but i'll try now

Comment: @edwin, adding to `.bashrc` didn't help for first

Comment: zsh does not use either .bashrc or .zsh , it uses `.zshrc` So, in `~/.zshrc`, add or edit your path, `PATH=$PATH:/your/directory` .

Comment: @boodhi.zazen it was a typo. '.zsh' -> '.zshrc'

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, Oops, right. RiaD, you might one to try adding the path to `.profile` and then in `.zshrc` use a conditional to test if it is already present in PATH. Check [ZshUserGuide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html#l24).

Comment: IMO, when you make a shortcut or laucher you should always use the full path. I am not sure why the launcher is not working. Is there some reason your program is not in a standard location on your path or in ~/bin or in /usr/local ? Although not an answer, placing your program in a standard location may be a viable work around.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I want run it using `gmrun` and terminal without full path (just lazyness). I will consider placing to common location, through

Comment: @RiaD you could put a symbolic link to it in a common location instead of moving the binary itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is basically based on Eliah Kagan's one and contains what I really did.

I've added to `~/.pam_environment`

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/home/riad/scripts
```

But at least on my PC it was not parsed on tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) login but was parsed on graphical login. (Even locale settings that are created by unity wasn't work in non-graphical login)

The reason is that there was following line in pam configuration file for lightdm (`/etc/pam.d/lightdm`) :

```
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

I've added same line to `/etc/pam.d/login` between

```
@include common-session
```

and

```
@include common-password
```

## Be careful! Bad `.pam_environment` file may broke your login.

Answer (score 5):

#### Setting an Environment Variable for All Logins (no matter what type)

The best way is to **[use `~/.pam_environment`.](https://askubuntu.com/a/244723/22949)** For example, to add `/opt/blah/bin` to the end of your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29), you'd put this in the `.pam_environment` file in your home directory:

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/opt/blah/bin
```

#### Setting Environment Variables Globally (but don't do this unless you need to)

If you want to add something to the `PATH` for *all users*, use `/etc/environment` instead. Confusingly, `/etc/environment` and `~/.pam_environment` don't use the same syntax. While neither is actually a script, `/etc/environment` looks like a script (*without* any `export` commands). So, if you wanted to add `/opt/blah/bin` to the end of everybody's `PATH`, and the `PATH` line in `/etc/environment` started out as

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

then you would change it to:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/blah/bin"
```

#### Analysis

Most Bourne-style shells, including `bash`, will source `~/.profile` when they are started as a login shell. `zsh` is an unusual exception; it will only do this if it is invoked with the name of one of the traditional Bourne-style shells. That is, if you *call* `zsh` by the name `sh` or `ksh` (most commonly achieved by creating a symbolic link to `zsh` with one of those names), it will behave like them and source `~/.profile` (if it is a login shell). Otherwise, it will not. (Source: [`man zsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/zsh.1.html).)

This is why `zsh` in a [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) session (for example, where you go to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) doesn't set the `PATH` environment variable from `~/.profile`. It is a login shell, but `zsh` is special; it does not behave like traditional Bourne-style shells unless it is pretending to be one.

Why does `zsh` running a Terminal window have the environment variables you set in `~/.profile`? Because *they were already set in your graphical session before you launched the Terminal*. When you log in graphically, the display manager (which provides the graphical login screen and manages graphical sessions) *acts like a login shell*. Usually it sources `~/.profile` (though it is not *guaranteed* that it will do so, and occasionally someone changes desktop environments only to find that `~/.profile` is no longer sourced when they log in graphically).

There is nothing about text-based virtual consoles that makes `~/.profile` not get sourced. For example, if your shell were `bash` instead of `zsh` and you logged on in a virtual console, `~/.profile` would be sourced. The issue is that, unlike the reliable behavior of a traditional Bourne-style shell, and the not quite as reliable behavior of a display manager starting a graphical login session, `zsh` does not source `~/.profile` when it's your login shell.

Similarly, with environment variables set in `~/.profile`, if you were to log in remotely (for example, by enabling SSH and logging in that way), `~/.profile` would not be sourced.

This applies to the global file `/etc/profile` too, by the way. If you set environment variables globally there, you'd experience the same behavior you're seeing setting environment variables for your user in `~/.profile`.

The solution, **provided that you don't need to write a scripted test to determine the contents of your environment variables**, is to set user-specific environment variables in `~/.pam_environment` and systemwide (i.e., for-all-users) environment variables in `/etc/environment`.

When you do that, [PAM](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man7/pam.7.html) (specifically, [`pam_env.so`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/pam_env.8.html)) sets the variables on login, for basically every type of login, and does so *before* the login shell (e.g., `zsh`, `bash` for most people) or login-shell-like thing (e.g., a display manager) sources its own login configuration files. This is the [generally recommended way to set environment variables on Ubuntu these days](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables).

This way solves the problem of some login shells not always sourcing `~/.profile` and `/etc/profile` (which is the problem you're experiencing). It also solves the occasional problem of a display manager not sourcing that file as it initializes a graphical login session (this is a problem which you are *not* experiencing).

#### Alternatives

What if:

- you need to set environment variables on login, based on the results of scripted tests? *Or*
- you just don't want to use `.pam_environment` (or for systemwide variables, `/etc/environment`?

If you weren't using `zsh`, but instead used `bash` or another more traditional Bourne-style shell, then you could just set your environment variables in `~/.profile` (or `/etc/profile` for systemwide variables). On occasion there is a configuration where this doesn't set them for graphical login sessions, but usually it works.

Setting them in `~/.bashrc` *will not work for this purpose*. Essentially only `bash` sources that file, so it will work neither when `zsh` is your login shell nor when the display manager acts as your login shell. (In other words, in your situation that will never work at all.)

Thus, if you need a script that is sourced for all types of login, and `~/.profile` is being sourced for your graphical sessions, you can simply:

- modify `zsh`'s configuration to source `~/.profile`, *or*
- make both `zsh`'s configuration and `~/.profile` source a third, shared file. (This could even be added to a separate configuration file for graphical sessions, [such as `.xsession`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4628/11938), if that turned out to be needed later.)

Of those two options, the second one is better unless you've read through the contents of ~/.profile`and made sure they--and the contents of any script sourced from`.profile`--won't cause problems if sourced by`zsh`. (It usually should not, but you never know.)

The best configuration file to modify, to make `zsh` source `~/.profile` (or some other script) on login, is `~/.zprofile`. This corresponds to `~/.profile` on more traditional Bourne-style shells. (Strictly speaking, it's `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`, but `$ZDOTDIR` is typically `~`.)

You would add the line `source $HOME/.profile` to that file.

I emphasize, however, that if just need to perform simple assignment to environment variables (including recursive assignment where an environment variables is assigned an expression containing itself and/or other environment variables), **you should just use `~/.pam_environment`** as explained above (or `/etc/environment` for systemwide environment variables).

Comment: I've tried with `.pam_environment`. It works on terminal in Unity but not virtual console session(path just didn't appended)

Comment: @RiaD What does? Are you saying `.pam_environment` is not affecting your environment variables in a virtual console, either? Are you starting a new virtual console session (i.e., logging out and back in)? If that is the case, then the most likely explanation is that variables *are* set from `.pam_environment`, but then one of your `zsh` configuration files replaces `PATH` with its own `PATH`, trashing them. The solution is to make any setting of `PATH` in `zsh`'s configuration files recursive. If you're unsure if this is happening, please post `.zshenv`, `.zprofile`, `.zlogin` and `.zshrc`.

Comment: @RiaD Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: They aren't set(after reboot). It is not about `$PATH` only `PAPERSIZE=a4` in this file and `echo $PATH` prints a4 in unity termonal but nothing in tty

Comment: What do you mean when you say "It is not about `$PATH`"? What does `PAPERSIZE` have to do with this? You can set that variable in `.pam_environment`, but both your question (this one) and the post I linked to about `.pam_environment` are about `PATH` and *not* about `PAPERSIZE`. Are you saying that setting `PAPERSIZE=a4` causes `PATH` to contain `a4`? What variable or variables are you setting, and how? What's the contents of your `.pam_environment` file? What are the contents of the four `zsh` configuration files I mentioned?

Comment: I mean PATH is not set and PAPERSIZE is not set too and both are set in Unity terminal. So it's seems that the problem is that `.pam_environment` is not used in tty1 login but not in overriding

Comment: Ah, I see. If I understand you correctly, you're saying that even when you try to use `.pam_environment` to set another environment variable that would not likely have been (re)set in any zsh configuration file, it still does not work. Therefore, it appears `.pam_environment` is not being used in the virtual console. I believe your reasoning is correct; that suggests the problem is not just due to the contents of any `zsh` configuration file. What I am saying is: It should be used, though, since it doesn't depend on login shell. So, *exactly what* do you have in `.pam_environment`?

Comment: [.pam_environment](http://pastie.org/8190746)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9886/discussion-between-eliah-kagan-and-riad)

Comment: .pam_environemt doest work fr gdm3 logging into default X session. very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could just source your .profile in your .zshrc file.

Besides that, 
as you're using zsh, you can add the following to your .zshrc:

```
typeset -U path

# If you want it at the front of your path
path=({/custom/path/bin "${path[@]}")

# If you want it at the end of your path
path+=(/custom/path/bin)
```

How this works:

In zsh, the `$PATH` variable is bound to the `$path` variable; `$path` is an array, and `$PATH` is a scalar with the elements of `$path` joined by `:` (identical to `${(j|:|)path}`). `typeset -U path` makes the elements of the `path` array (and thus the `$PATH`) unique.

```
   typeset [ {+|-}AEFHUafghklprtuxmz ] [ -LRZi [ n ]] [ name[=value] ... ]
   typeset -T [ {+|-}Urux ] [ -LRZ [ n ]] SCALAR[=value] array [ sep ]
          Set or display attributes and values for shell parameters.
          (...)
          -U     For  arrays  (but  not for associative arrays), keep only
                 the first occurrence of each duplicated value.  This  may
                 also  be  set for colon-separated special parameters like
                 PATH or FIGNORE, etc.  This flag has a different  meaning
                 when used with -f; see below.
```