# How to set a socks proxy server only for one user?

Tags: 13.04, proxy, settings

in Ubuntu 13.04 I tried to insert

```
export socks_proxy=socks://address:port
```

into `~/.profile` but this is not working.

PS: I need to set it only for a user so not in /etc/enviroment.

Comment: Which client tool should use this env variable?

Answer (score 2):

A few points:

- Environment variables are case-sensitive. Environment variables like this *tend* to be uppercase.
- If you're testing in bash, note the top of the `~/.profile` file:

  ```
  # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
  # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
  # exists.
  # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
  # the files are located in the bash-doc package.
  ```
- [The help wiki recommends using `~/.pam_environment`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables) instead of other files for session environment variables.
- Its syntax [is different](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125421/how-to-open-pam-environment) than what you're expecting. See: http://linux.die.net/man/5/pam_env.conf
- So (assuming `~/.pam_environment`) you're probably looking for:

  ```
  SOCKS_PROXY DEFAULT=socks://address:port
  ```

Otherwise this is probably just a case issue.

---

You mention that you're using a browser and in there may lie the actual issue. Firefox, ignores environment variables by default. There is a plugin that will look for environment variables though (it's quite old):

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/environment-proxy/

I'm not sure how other browsers handle these things but I wouldn't be surprised if they do also ignore them.

Comment: Hello,
thank you for the reply.

Actually when you use the system settings to set the proxy globally it exports it lowercase in /etc/environement. That's why I used the lowercase version.

By the way I tried ~/.pam-environment and it is correctly exporting the variable (I check using env), but still the browser in not connecting through the proxy.

I tried both socks_proxy and SOCKS_PROXY.

Comment: @Gius1982 Fair enough on the formatting and name. I've added an edit about browsers not using environment variables.